# Channel bonding on Windows

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection, bonding

How can I configure on Windows a proxy server software (such as Squid, Wingate or CCProxy) to do channel bonding amongst multiple adapters but without needing to connect to external servers on the cloud?

Any other solution to achieve it easily, preferably with a GUI is welcome.

Channel bonding is a method for to increase throughput and redundancy by spreading individual packets amongst multiple Internet connections at the packet-level.

The Speedify software does it automatically by establishing a connection to its server on the cloud which acts as a middleman between you and the rest of the Internet. But I'm looking for a free alternative not needing to connect to any external server.

This is different from load balancing because the latter spreads sockets (instead of packets) amongst multiple Internet connections, and no individual socket can be sped up beyond your fastest available Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

IP-level channel bonding is where you can send packets from a single TCP connection over multiple paths.

This requires the co-operation of your ISP.

This is because incoming packets back to you would need to be load-balanced back to you over your multiple connections.  This needs to be handled at your ISP.  There are some BGP options which can be used for multiple routes to a destination and I believe there are options to specify priority of routes to use.  So you may be able to do this with BGP, but again you'll need to get that set up at your ISP, and they will probably charge you a monthly fee for this.

Outbound you can spread the packets over multiple connections, so you can possibly achieve bandwidth aggregation for outbound, as long as your ISP doesn't consider this to be spoofing and block the packets that come over the non-matching connection.

Comment: But I mean using several different ISP simultaneously.